# Separating my library to Libs, Core & Addons

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm pretty new in this world so bear with me.

I have my big library that i'm trying to convert it to es6 modules, `babel` & `webpack` to bundle it later on to several files.

My library folders look like this

```
--src
  -- core
     -- folder1
     -- folder2
  -- addons
     -- addon 1
        -- addon 1 files and folders
     -- addon 2
        -- addon 2 files and folders
  -- libs
     -- internal
        -- internal lib1 
        -- internal lib2 
     -- external
        -- external lib1 
        -- external lib2
```

My library code is separate to 2 - the core code and the addons and i'm using some libraries (`libs` folder)

My wish is that:

- All internal libs will be bundeled into one libs file
- External libs are excluded from bundle
- All core files will be bundleds into one core file
- All my addons will be bundleds into each addon file
- Note: addons are using core files and are not to bundle in them

final result:
libs.js
core.js
addon1.js
addon2.js

My clients will have to use the first 2 js files. and Addon will be included as they wish.

So far I've managed to separate my internal lib using `CommonsChunkPlugin`

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "libs",
    minChunks: function(module){
      return module.context && module.context.indexOf("\\libs\\internal\\") !== -1;
    },
  });
```

External libs are ignored using `null-loader`

```
{
   test: /libs\\external/,
   loader: 'null-loader'
},
```

my entry point js looks like this

import a from

```
"./core/a";
import b from "./core/b";
import addon1C from "./addons/addon1/c";

const myLib = {
   core: {a,b},
   addons: {addon1C}
}

export {myLib}
```

and now the problem starts with the core and addons.

If i'm skipping the addons part, in my client side including 2 scripts (libs, core)

and simply `myLib.core.a` is working.

The question do i prevent the bundling of the core code in the addons.

I've tried to do it with another chunk plugin but it causes some errors in the modules because the addon is using the core code and the entry point is using the addons to export it, so it doesn't find the module.

Tried 2 entry points so i will have the first entry point without the addons
and export the addons separately, but now the core code is bundled in it.

So, How do I do that ?
Or if there is a better way to do any of what I've done so far. i'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that, I think you have to use a different approach. I had a similar situation where some other team needed to extend the core functionality of the application on demand.

In order to achieve that, I had to make sure that the **core** and the **add-on's** don't communicate each other directly. Instead, your core code should provide some kind of API that will be used by your add-on's.

From the other end, when your add-on's will try to import the core, you will have to provide a `shim` file, not the core itself.

I will try to write a couple of examples down here:

```
// core
export default const Core = {}
const addons = []
Core.addPlugin = function(addOn) {
   addons.push(addOn) // or doing something else
}

// shim-core.js
export default typeof window.Core !== undefined ? window.Core : Core

// add-on
import Core from 'shim-core'
const addOn = function() {
   // something funky
   return {}
}
Core.addPlugin(addOn)
```

I hope it helps you to understand the 'architecture'

Comment: So you suggest entry point per addon if i got it right ? and what about the code in the addon.. should it just use the `Core` objects without importing the modules before ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Remember a couple of things: 1. expose the `Core` object using the `expose-loader`. Or you can use the `import-loader` to import the shim when the add-on module is processed. 2. Do not import Core features directly

Comment: Didn't quiet understand your with the expose-loader/import-loader. I am the library - when i do export my `Core` it is being exported in the global context. I don't need any other library to expose.

Comment: Well it all depends on your configuration :) if it works fine with your codebase, I am happy with that